# why using join table doesn't get the the result intended

Tags: join, abap, select-options

I have an issue with my code ABAP and I can't figure out what it is.

I want to get 3 fields from `EKKO` and 1 field from `EKPO` after select-options:

```
SELECT-OPTIONS: s_ebeln FOR ekpo-ebeln.

SELECT  eko~ebeln eko~aedat ekp~elikz
  FROM ekko as eko
  JOIN ekpo as ekp
  ON eko~ebeln = ekp~ebeln
  into table it_eko2
  WHERE eko~ebeln in s_ebeln.
```

The issue is I'm getting nothing for `ekp~elikz` (if I remove the condition `WHERE eko~ebeln in s_ebeln` I get the fields needed).

I tried to get 4 fields `eko~ebeln eko~aedat ekp~elikz` from corresponding to the PO numbers range entered by the users but I'm getting the three fields from `ekko` only instead.

Any help please ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the syntax, the only possibility is that there's an issue in the values you query. Don't forget that the data is "client specific" so you must run your query in the right client.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: try using inner join instead of join.

Comment: join by default without further keywords is inner join

{ [INNER] JOIN } | {LEFT | RIGHT  [OUTER] JOIN}

Comment: Code worked me....

Answer (score 0):

Actully the select statement you provided should work.

There is the output from my sample data:

| ebeln | aedat | ebelp | elikz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0044686616 | 20220101 | 00001 | X |
| 0044686616 | 20220101 | 00002 |  |
| 0044686616 | 20220101 | 00003 | X |
| 0044686616 | 20220101 | 00004 |  |
| 0044686616 | 20220101 | 00005 | X |
| 0044686618 | 20220101 | 00001 | X |
| 0044686618 | 20220101 | 00002 |  |

And the program - I just selected additionally the ebelp (item number):

```
SELECT eko~ebeln, eko~aedat, ekp~ebelp, ekp~elikz
    FROM ekko AS eko
    JOIN ekpo AS ekp
    ON eko~ebeln = ekp~ebeln
    INTO TABLE @DATA(it_eko2)
    WHERE eko~ebeln IN @s_ebeln.
 
  IF sy-subrc IS INITIAL.
    LOOP AT it_eko2 ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_eko2>).
      WRITE: / |{ <fs_eko2>-ebeln }  { <fs_eko2>-aedat } { <fs_eko2>-ebelp } { <fs_eko2>-elikz }|.
    ENDLOOP.
  ENDIF.
```

Please note that every entry in the header table `EKKO` (**E**in**K**aufsbeleg**KO**pf - Purchasing document header) table corresponds to *1 or more entries* in the position table `EKPO`  (**E**n**K**aufsbeleg**PO**sition - Purchasing document item) table.

The field `elikz` (**E**nd**LI**eferungs**K**enn**Z**eichen - Delivery completed indicator) has char(1) type, which is an indicator, and contais either `' '` (space) or `'X'` symbol - maybe no item in your selection has 'X' set and it looks like as nothing was selected.

Try also to set a breakpoint and check in the debugger what data is actully present in s_ebeln range table - below is the sample from my case (selected two single values):

Table: S_EBELN[]

| Row | SIGN | OPTION | LOW | HIGH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | I | EQ | 0044686618 |  |
| 2 | I | EQ | 0044686616 |  |

If the condition range table is empty - all entries from the db-tables will be selected, which could be a lot of data.

And one more step - try to use the transaction `se16 / se16n` to manually select the document(s) by ebeln and check wheather the documents in question exist and which values the fields have.